# Why do predictors not match variable name sin model?

Tags: r, regression

```
train <- read.csv("train.csv", header=T)

> str(train)
'data.frame':   188318 obs. of  132 variables:
 $ id    : int  1 2 5 10 11 13 14 20 23 24 ...
 $ cat1  : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ cat2  : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ cat3  : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ cat4  : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...

predictors <- names(subset(train, select = -c(id,loss)))
fit <- lm(paste("loss ~ ",paste(predictors, collapse="+"),sep=""), data=train)
```

There are 966 coefficients when I look at summary of fit? I expected there to be only the same as the length of "predictors" minus 2 (id and loss).

```
> variable.names(fit)
  [1] "(Intercept)" "cat1B"       "cat2B"       "cat3B"       "cat4B"       "cat5B"       "cat6B"      
  [8] "cat7B"       "cat8B"       "cat9B"       "cat10B"      "cat11B"      "cat12B"      "cat13B"     
 [15] "cat14B"      "cat15B"      "cat16B"      "cat17B"      "cat18B"      "cat19B"      "cat20B"     
 [22] "cat21B"      "cat22B"      "cat23B"      "cat24B"      "cat25B"      "cat26B"      "cat27B"     
 [29] "cat28B"      "cat29B"      "cat30B"      "cat31B"      "cat32B"      "cat33B"      "cat34B"
```

Then further down (don't want to paste them all)

```
"cat110AK"    "cat110AL"    "cat110AM"    "cat110AN"    "cat110AO"    "cat110AP"    "cat110AR"   
[393] "cat110AS"    "cat110AT"    "cat110AU"    "cat110AV"    "cat110AW"    "cat110AX"    "cat110AY"   
[400] "cat110B"     "cat110BA"    "cat110BB"    "cat110BC"    "cat110BD"    "cat110BE"    "cat110BF"   
[407] "cat110BG"    "cat110BI"    "cat110BJ"    "cat110BK"    "cat110BL"    "cat110BM"    "cat110BN"
```

What is "B" and "AT" etc which is being appended to the variables? Why are there more than 130?

Comment: Because they are dummy variables, ie. a new variable is created for every level of every factor column you have.

Comment: Oh. I get it. So r will boil every feature down to a binary 1 or 0 for each level in a factor? If building a "baseline" first shot model to explore, build and expand upon, is it normal to let R do this for you?

Comment: this is standard behaviour for `lm`, however you can can also do it manually with `model.matrix` or `dummyVars`.